# Proof that $r(AB)=r(BA)$, where $r$ is a rank

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

I want to prove that $r(AB) = r(BA)$, where $r$ is a rank. $A$ is a square matrix and $B$ is an invertible matrix.

Can I use this?

$r(AB) \le min \{r(A), r(B)\} = r(A)$, and from the other side

$r(A) = r(BB^{-1}ABB^{-1}) \le min \{r(BB^{-1}), r(AB), r(B^{-1})\} = r(AB)$

hence $\;$ $r(AB) = r(A)$, and

$r(BA) \le min \{r(B), r(A)\} = r(A)$, and from the other side

$r(A) = r(B^{-1}BAB^{-1}B) \le min \{r(B^{-1}), r(BA), r(B^{-1}B))\} = r(BA)$

hence $\;$ $r(BA) = r(A)$,

and we proved that $r(AB)=r(BA)$.

Is this proof correct? Thank you.

Comment: Why not reason conceptually ? $r(AB)$ is the dimension of the image of $AB$, which is the same as that of $A$ or $BA$, as invertible  maps preserve the dimension.

Comment: Because it is a chapter before the linear mappings, so I wanted to prove it somehow by the rank theorem, but thank you for the idea.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your proof is correct, assuming (of course) you know the fact that $r(AB)\leq \min\{r(A), r(B)\}$.  One thing I wonder about is why you write $A=B^{-1}BAB^{-1}B$?  Is it not enough to write $A=B^{-1}BA$?

Comment: Yes, that is pretty easier, thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Image:

$Im(AB)\subset Im(A)=Im(A(BB^{-1}))=Im(AB(B^{-1}))\subset Im(AB)$

So for $B$ invertible we have $Im(AB)=Im(A)$

Kernel:

$x\in Ker(A)\Rightarrow Ax=0\Rightarrow BAx=0\Rightarrow x\in Ker(BA)$
$x\in Ker(BA)\Rightarrow BAx=0\Rightarrow Ax=B^{-1}0=0\Rightarrow x\in Ker(A)$

So for $B$ invertible we have $Ker(BA)=Ker(A)$

Now all this being in finite dimension we can apply the rank-theorem, and for any B invertible: $$rank(A)=rank(AB)=rank(BA)$$